How to insert a PDF brochure (10.5cm x 29.7cm) with correct printing order into a LaTeX document (A4) without margins?
I am working on a LaTeX document and I would like to include a brochure (in PDF format) that is formatted as a long-folded DIN A4 sheet. The dimensions of each page in the PDF are 10.5cm (width) by 29.7cm (height), which corresponds to a long-format booklet.
Here’s what I am trying to do:
I want to insert this PDF into my LaTeX document (which is A4 size) such that each LaTeX page contains 2 pages of my PDF brochure placed side by side, in correct printing order so that when printed and folded, the pages appear in the correct sequence. In my case that would be 12,1,2,11,10,3,4,9,8,5,6,7.
Finally, where I have not succeeded so far, I would like to eliminate any margins between the pages when they are displayed next to each other on the LaTeX page. (There should be no extra space around the PDF pages.)
I have tried using the pdfpages package with the following code:
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images 
\usepackage{pdfpages} % For inserting the PDF 
\begin{document} 
\includepdf[pages={12,1,2,11,10,3,4,9,8,5,6,7}, nup=2x1]{myformattedbrochurewithmeasures10-5cmtimes29-7cm.pdf} 
\end{document}


But I am still getting unwanted margins between the pages, and the layout isn't as I expect. (I have read something about pdfcrop, but I'm not quite getting the hang of it yet)
Could someone explain how I can insert the PDF in a way that uses the space efficiently and eliminates margins between the PDF pages, while also ensuring the correct printing order for the booklet?
Thank you!
(One last thing: Will the PDF quality become worse by using those LaTeX tools? Just making sure, this approach will work for printing quality...)

I tried using \documentclass[a4paper]{article}. Now the problem seems to be solved. How come?

You said:

I tried using \documentclass[a4paper]{article}. Now the problem seems
to be solved. How come?

This is because A4 paper is not default for article. Rather, the standard size is the size of "US Letter" (which is an American paper size thing, different from the A series). If you try fitting A4 or A5 paper on US Letter, you'll get problems because the sizes don't match up. To see this, here is some easy code that returns the paperwidth and paperlenght of your chosen document class:

\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{calc} 
\newlength{\docwidth} 
\newlength{\docheight} 
\setlength{\docwidth}{\paperwidth} 
\setlength{\docheight}{\paperheight} 

\makeatletter
\def\convertto#1#2{\strip@pt\dimexpr #2*65536/\number\dimexpr 1#1}
\makeatother

\begin{document} 

\begin{table}[htb]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{c|cc}
       & Width [mm]  & Height [mm] \\
       \hline
       & & \\
        Document & \convertto{mm}{\the\docwidth} & \convertto{mm}{\the\docheight}  \\
        & & \\
        A4 & 210 & 297 \\
        A5 & 148 & 210 \\
        US Letter & 216 & 279
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}

The code used conversion from pt to mm from this answer.
Anyway, we see that the standard \documentclass{article} is 2cm shorter than A4 paper and 0.6cm wider. So, when you try to fit 2 A5 pages on the US letter size, it's not a good fit. If you run the code with \documentclass[a4paper]{article} you'll see that the dimensions match up with A4 paper (as it should).

Once in a while, an apparently complex question has a simple answer, unrelated to the complexity of the question. This seems to be one of those occasions.

@rallg except that the default paper size is not determined by the class at all in the case of article, though the default layout size is. to complicate things further, engines may interfere .... so it is not really quite so simple :(.
